# How to implement numpy broadcast mechanism with mkl?

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

How to implement numpy broadcast mechanism with mkl?

I have been confused, how to use mkl to efficiently implement the broadcast mechanism in numpy (Element wise operator "+","-","*")?

such as
2-D array sub 1-D array

```
[[1,2,3],              [[0,0,0],
 [4,5,6],  - [1,2,3] =  [3,3,3],
 [7,8,9]]               [6,6,6]]
```

And the second operation (can be understood as a matrix multiplied by a diagonal matrix)
2-D array multiply 1-D array(Element wise multiply )

```
[[1,2,3],               [[1,4,9],
 [4,5,6],  *  [1,2,3] =  [4,10,18],
 [7,8,9]]                [7,16,27]]
```

I tried to implement with the for loop +cblas_dscal/vdSub.
But I think this is not efficient, I don't know if there is any better implementation.

Comment: The `mkl` code is called by compiled numpy code.  You don't invoke it directly from Python.  It's a library that is linked to `numpy` during setup or compilation, not something you consciously use while running interpreted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just broadcast the second array to two dimensions with `arr2[None, :]`. This yields the following code:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9]])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,3])

print(arr1 - arr2[None, :])
# Out: [[0 0 0]
#       [3 3 3]
#       [6 6 6]]
print(arr1 * arr2[None, :])
# Out: [[ 1,  4,  9],
#       [ 4, 10, 18],
#       [ 7, 16, 27]]
```

If you broadcast your arrays like this, numpy will use optimizations like mkl to perform the requested operations like multiplications.
More information on broadcasting and expanding array dimensions with `None` or `np.newaxis` can be found here:

- [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)
- [Expancing dimensions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: You may still upvote and accept my answer, since it answered your question. :)

Comment: @Scotty1- Is the element-wise multiply/add/etc in numpy automatically using MKL/BLAS/etc to parallelize these operations?

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés Yes, if MKL etc. is correctly installed (which should be, if you install a scientific python package which already includes numpy and the scipy stack).